# Uninstall Ubuntu 12.10 and revert back to Windows 7

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 and regretted it almost immediately. Don't ask why, I was just wondering if I can completely uninstall Ubuntu and then go back to Windows 7 with my original C: drive at full capacity (getting rid of the Ubuntu partition). If so, how?

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to ask why. Besides, why didn't you try it out before you installed it?

Comment: From your question ("go back" to Windows 7) I got the impression you had completely replaced Windows with Ubuntu, rather than dual-booting between them - but the other answer assumes otherwise - could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a case of installing Windows 7, which involves booting from the Windows 7 installation disc and installing over your complete hard drive.  Whether or not you have Ubuntu (or any OS) already on that drive doesn't really change the procedure, except that perhaps the installation may prompt you as to whether you want to overwrite existing partitions and/or use the whole drive (you want to use the whole drive).

This isn't really an Ubuntu related question, so I'll leave the specifics of how to do this to other sites on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify how you have installed it - by using WUBI or using a separate partition. If there is a separate partition and you can boot into windows 7, then the easy way is installing "easybcd community edition", then overwriting the boot-loader with win 7 boot-loader and then deleting the partitions from the windows disk manager.

EasyBCD download page - http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml